# How to define recursive data structures in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a BNF-like DSL in Swift.
In Scala, [gll-combinators](https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators) has a nice approach:

```scala
lazy val expr: Parser[Any] = (
    "(" ~ expr ~ ")" ^^ { _ + _ + _ }
  | ""
)
```

This creates a parser which references itself.

When I try to do the same in Swift (using a `lazy var` in a class, or `@autoclosure` in a function) I get a 'Variable used within its own initial value' error.

In a simple example

```
class Node {
    private var node: Node
    init(node: Node) { self.node = node }
}
```

I want to create a Node with its member `node` pointing to `self`.

```
lazy var node = Node(node) // error
```

Is there a way around?

Comment: Please show some actual Swift code and explain what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to define a class where a property does reference `self`?

Maybe something like this?

```
class Node {
    private var node: Node!

    init(node: Node) {
        self.node = node
    }

    init() {
        self.node = self
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
let node = Node()
```

I had to make the `node` property optional to make this work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to find a nicer syntax so that complex structures can also be described more easily. But I guess I will need this two-stage approach.

Comment: Especially type inference does not work any more when splitting into allocation and assignment. My real 'Node' has type parameters and now I have to specify them explicitly.